# Why doesn't this code return a "deadlock" error?

Tags: go, deadlock

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func Extract(url string) ([]string, error) {
    http.Get(url)

    var links []string
    return links, nil
}

func crawl(url string) []string {
    list, _ := Extract(url)
    return list
}

func main() {
    var ch = make(chan int)
    ch <- 1
}
```

If I remove the net/http import, it will return a "deadlock" error as expected. But if I import this package, although I didn't invoke the Extract func, the "deadlock" will not appear.

Comment: Your code, copied to the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1Aw3blw7SDg), *does* abort with a deadlock error.

Comment: Yes, It's true.But If you run it use the "go run" command, the deadlock error will not appeared, I don't know why

Comment: What version of Go are you using? What *exactly* does one need to do to reproduce the problem? See [mcve]

Answer (score 10):

Importing the net package starts background polling Goroutines that effectively disable the deadlock detector.

You can see the discussion for a similar issue here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12734

Comment: TIL... Interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This issue has been bothered me two days.Your reply is so helpful to me, but I still not clear about the details.